# SSIS calling Powershell - the term is not recognized

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and SSIS. I want to call a Powershell script file from an Execute Process Task but it keeps failing. If I open Powershell ISE and do a `File > Open`, my script runs fine, so the issue is not with the actual `.ps1` file.

This is my execute process task - obviously using the correct servername\path in the real world:

[image]

So, I took a step back, opened Powershell and pasted the argument from SSIS in:

```
-F "\\servername\path\myPSFile.ps1"
```

But I get the error:

> -F : The term '-F' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I then tried:

```
-File "\\servername\path\myPSFile.ps1"
```

but got:

> -File : The term '-File' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I then tried:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "\\servername\path\myPSFile.ps1"
```

But received the error:

```
The term ExecutionPolicy is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I then ran:

```
Get-Module -All
```

And all I have installed is:

```
Binary \ Script \ Manifest
```

Do I need another module installing?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the details of the execute process task to take a look at that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the **Arguments** setting value needs to be adjusted as follows:

```
-command "\\servername\path\myPSFile.ps1"
```

Also, there is a need to specify the **ExecutionPolicy** as Unrestricted.

So, the final Arguments would be as follows:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "\\servername\path\myPSFile.ps1"
```

Please check this link for all the details: [How to Execute a PowerShell Script from an SSIS Package](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6172/execute-powershell-script-from-ssis-package/)

Comment: sorry, similar error, I have updated original post